# Unit testing a Delegate of a request parameter of a repository C#,Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

In the below code,I need to check whether in the request "System" is added with the value "Portal".

```
var rq = new RestBaseRequest{AmendHeaders = x => x.Add("Systerm", "Portal")};

var repositoryResponse = await this.restRepository.GetAsync(rq,cancellationToken, loggingContext);
```

The RestBaseRequest class looks like  below

```
  public class RestBaseRequest
        {
            public RestBaseRequest();

            public Action<HttpRequestHeaders> AmendHeaders { get; set; }
        }
```

I tried the way as below

```
[Test]
        public async Task TestRequestHeaderConatainsRequestingSystem()
        {
            // Arrange
            var restRepository = new Mock<IRestRepository<LifeBondResponse>>();
            RestBaseRequest requestBase = null;
            CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
            LoggingContext context = null;


 restRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(
                    It.IsAny<RestBaseRequest>(),
                    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
                    It.IsAny<LoggingContext>())).Callback((RestBaseRequest baseRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken, LoggingContext loggingContext) =>
                    {
                        requestBase = baseRequest;
                        token = cancellationToken;
                        context = loggingContext;
                    })
                .ReturnsAsync(new Service<LifeBondResponse>
                {
                    Status = GeneralResponseType.Success,
                });

 var request = new CustomerRequest<InvestmentBondPolicy>
            {
                TypeOfRequest = CustomerRetrieveType.Number,
                Id = "12345",
                Data = new Policy()
                {
                    PolicyNumber = "123456",
                }
            };

            var repository = new BondRepository(this.authoriseService.Object, restRepository.Object);
            var rs = await repository.GetPolicyAsync(request, new CancellationToken());

}
```

since there is no public properties in RestBaseRequest,I couldn't able to do check further.Is there any way to test this or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got it myself,

```
[Test]
    public async Task TestRequestHeaderConatainsRequestingSystem()
    {
        // Arrange
        var restRepository = new Mock<IRestRepository<LifeBondResponse>>();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        restRepository
                .Setup(
                    x => x.GetAsync(
                        It.IsAny<RestBaseRequest>(),
                        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
                        It.IsAny<ILoggingContext>()))
                .Callback((RestBaseRequest serviceRequest,
                        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                        ILoggingContext loggingContext) =>
                        {
                          serviceRequest.AmendHeaders(client.DefaultRequestHeaders);
                        }).ReturnsAsync(new Service<LifeBondResponse> { Status = GeneralResponseType.Success, });
        var request = new CustomerRequest<Policy>
        {
            TypeOfRequest = CustomerRetrieveType.PolicyNumber,
            Id = "12345",
            Data = new Policy()
            {
                PolicyNumber = "123456",
                                }
        };
        var repository = new LifeBondRepository(this.authoriseService.Object, restRepository.Object);

        // Act
        await repository.GetPolicyAsync(request, new CancellationToken());

        // Assert
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Should().NotBeNull();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Any(x => x.Key == "System").Should().Be(true);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.GetValues("System").First().Should().Be("Portal");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two tests:

- one that checks that `GetAsync` calls the callback on the request
- another one that checks that this concrete request adds `Portal` to `System`

In the first one you pass a mocked request into the repository and in the second, call the callback with a mocked `HttpRequestHeaders`.

The second test might look like this:

```
var headers = new HttpRequestHeaders();
requestToTest.AmendHeaders( headers );
Assert.That( headers["System"], Is.EqualTo( "Portal" ) );
```

Full text:

```
public void MethodToTest( IRepository repository )
{
    var rq = new RestBaseRequest{AmendHeaders = x => x.Add("Systerm", "Portal")};
    var repositoryResponse = await repository.GetAsync(rq,cancellationToken, loggingContext);
}

public void TheTest()
{
     repositoryMock.Setup( x => x.GetAsync(...) ).Callback( (x,y,z) =>
     {
         var headers = new HttpRequestHeaders();
         x.AmendHeaders( headers );
         Assert.That( headers["System"], Is.EqualTo( "Portal" ) );
     });
     _subjectUnderTest.MethodToTest( repositoryMock.Object );
}
```

Comment: No problem in unit testing GetAsync ,I need suggestion on testing the request.I have already separate tests for testing GetAsync

Comment: The request doesn't really do a lot. Just call its callback and see if it modifies the `HttpRequestHeaders` as expected.

Comment: As I mentioned there is no public property exposed in RestBaseRequest class to verify HttpRequestHeaders

Comment: You don't need that, because you have it at hand because you created it yourself.

Comment: you mean  **RestBaseRequest requestBase = null;**  What should I check in requestBase object? I think I haven't understood

Comment: Put it anywhere where you got _the actual request created by the code you want to test_. That might be inside the mocked `GetAsync` call if you pass the mocked repository to the code under test.

Comment: I found myself a way.We can't create new object like **new HttpRequestHeaders()**,but  you comments helped me.

Comment: There's a way to create a `HttpRequestHeaders`: `new HttpRequestMessage().Headers` (also, you could call the internal constructor via reflection)